# How to add my obj model to a three.js scene?

Tags: 3d, three.js

Here is the link to the example http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock.  From what I can see in the source code the geometry is created in the code.  How would you go about putting your own model in there?

(Very new to JS and webGL so be gentle). Thanks in advance.

Edit:

In the example cubes are generated on the floor.  I would also like my model to sit on the floor.  This is how they did it:

// floor

```
            geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 100, 100 );
            geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );

            for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
                vertex.x += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
                vertex.y += Math.random() * 2;
                vertex.z += Math.random() * 20 - 10;

            }

            for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
                face.vertexColors[ 0 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 1 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 2 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

            }

            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            // objects, creates one cube

            geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );             

            material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { specular: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ) * 20;
            mesh.position.y = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 ) * 20 + 10;
            mesh.position.z = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ) * 20;
            scene.add( mesh );              

            objects.push( mesh );           

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

I've included the relevant scrips and have called the scene `scene` as you suggested. If i delete the code from  `// objects, creates one cube` down and replace it with my own model the floor get deleted and my model does not show:

```
             var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
                console.log( item, loaded, total );
            };

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'obj/springCastle.obj', 'obj/springCastle.mtl', function ( object ) {

                //set properties of object (i.e. position, rotation, etc);                  
                object.position.y = - 80;
                scene.add( object );

            } );
```

Sorry if its something blindingly obvious, but if you could help in anyway that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `THREE.OBJLoader` to add custom geometry from a .obj source. A short example of loading a .obj is below:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
};

var yourMaterialHere = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material.map = yourMaterialHere;
        }
    } );
    //set properties of object (i.e. position, rotation, etc);
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

This comes almost directly from the Three.js [WebGL OBJ loader example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html). There are many other [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/chrisbrasington/fcf701b424256d671c95) that implement this differently; a google search of ["load OBJ three.js"](https://www.google.com/search?q=load%20obj%20three.js) will help if you get stuck.

If you're trying to run this without a server while developing, make sure to check out [How To Run Things Locally](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) if you have not already. It's super helpful when using external files.

**Edit:** I forgot to include the `manager` definition in my example. It is now included. I had a `yourMaterialHere` variable so that you could define your own material but I've now included a defined example as well.

**Update:** Here is how it should look integrated into your code:

```
// floor

geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 100, 100 );
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );

for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
    vertex.x += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
    vertex.y += Math.random() * 2;
    vertex.z += Math.random() * 20 - 10;

}

for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
    face.vertexColors[ 0 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
    face.vertexColors[ 1 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
    face.vertexColors[ 2 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

}

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

// objects, loads an OBJ           

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { specular: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
};

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.material.map = material;
        }
    } );
    object.position.x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ) * 20;
    object.position.y = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 ) * 20 + 10;
    object.position.z = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ) * 20;
    scene.add( object );
    //objects.push( object); //This will most likely work, I just commented it out because it isn't strictly necessary to load the model
} );             



renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Really the only thing you need to do is replace `PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE` with the correct path. If you get a weird permission-y error while trying to load the model, make sure to check out the link above.

Comment: I'm using a localhost to test my code.  I seem to be having a few problems implementing the changes you suggested though.  

I've copied over the sourcecode from the pointerlock example but don't know where to put the code you suggested above within the file.  If I delete the geometry that is rendered in the code and replace it with my model it breaks.


I made sure to include the relivent loader:
<script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

Comment: I've made some updates to my code. If it doesn't work please let me know. Editing your question to include relevant parts of your code might be helpful in diagnosing the problem. For running my code: make sure your scene is called `scene` or else change my example to fix it. Also make sure you run this *after* you instantiate and set up the scene.

Comment: I have added some code that should help you understand what I'm having problems with :)

Comment: why there is error on child.material.map = my_material , Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'map' of undefined "said by chrome"